# Seamless mouseenter/mouseleave from multiple elements of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table with spanned rows. Some tds in the spanned rows have classes that are targeted via jQuery to fade in a popup when the mouse enters it. When the mouse leaves the td, the popup fades out.

Here's the table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Some Items</td>
            <td class="cell-popup">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell-popup">B</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
var cell = $('.cell-popup'),
        popup = $('.popup');

cell.on({
    mouseenter: function(e){
        popup.css({
            left: e.pageX + 'px',
            top: e.pageY + 'px'
        }).fadeIn()
    },
    mouseleave: function(e){
        popup.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

The question is, how can I make the popup not hide/show when the mouse leaves the current cell and enters a new .cell-popup? I want to treat both .cell-popups as "one" cell. Meaning, if coming from outside any .cell-popup and the mouse enters any .cell-popup, the popup should show. If I move from one .cell-popup to another .cell-popup without entering a non-.cell-popup element, the popup should just stay where it is.

Comment: where is .popup class in your html?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar there's no need to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*fadeOut* the popup after a timeout. If the mouse enters another `.cell-popup` before the timeout, clear the timeout - effectively preventing the fadeOut.

```
var fadeOutTimer = null;
cell.on({
    mouseenter: function(e){
        if(fadeOutTimer) { // already displayed, so clear the timeout
            clearTimeout(fadeOutTimer);
            fadeOutTimer = null;
        }
        else {
            popup.css({
                left: e.pageX + 'px',
                top: e.pageY + 'px'
            }).fadeIn();
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function(e){
        fadeOutTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            popup.fadeOut();
            fadeOutTimer = null;
        }, 500); // 500ms
    }
});
```

Discarding the timeout when the mouse enters the popup:

```
popup.on({
    mouseenter: function(e){
        if(fadeOutTimer) { // already displayed, so clear the timeout
            clearTimeout(fadeOutTimer);
            fadeOutTimer = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I do the same for the popups though? The popup appears where the mouse is pointed. So when I move the mouse a bit to the right, the mouse enters the popup and it disappears.

Comment: Discard the timeout when the mouse enters the popup. Answer updated.

Comment: whoops. Sorry about that. I was removing the popup after it fades out. I had to rewrite it to $('body').on({mouseenter:, mouseleave:}, '.popup'); Thanks, @techfoobar !

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `hover` method as explained in the API docs: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$('.cell-popup').hover(
  function(){$('.popup').show();},
  function(){$('.popup').hide();}
);
```